# Eloquent query with subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relation, laravel-filament

Since three days I'm working on following problem:

```
 protected function getTableQuery(): Builder
    {
        return User::
            where('age','>',21)
            ->AppendDistanceTo(
                $this->city->geo->long,
                $this->city->geo->lat,
                **lo**,
                **la**,
            );
        }
```

The Model User has user_id and a id for the city city_id.

In the model City there is longitude and latitude for each city_id.
How can I get the longitude and latitude in the query above, für **lo** and **la** from the related Model?

Thank you very much for helping!

I want to show the distance from a selected city (
$this->city->geo->long,$this->city->geo->lat)

to the city, where the user lives.

Answer (score 0):

Given your `User` model has a city relationship, and the `City` model has a `geo` relationship, you could eager load the city relation like so:

```php
User::where('age', '>', 21)
->with('city.geo')
```

Then, `$user->city->geo->long`